# Array index out of bounds when getting arguments

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Up until now I’ve managed to do various, simple things such as assigning to variables, calculations and what not, compiled it and all that good stuff…

This section is about decisions using `if` and `else` statements. Here’s the code:

```
public class Decision 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (argv[0].equals("xyz"))
            System.out.println("Login successful");
        else 
            System.out.println("Login incorrect");  
    }
}
```

So I compile the program in CMD and try to run it, but I get this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at Decision.main(Decision.java:5)

I understand there's a problem probably somewhere in the code but can't seem to find it- and I know once I have it will be blatantly obvious!

Comment: `args` contains application launcher arguments. If you don't have any it will be an array of size 0.

Comment: args[0] instead of argv[0]

Comment: Not "probably somewhere", on line 5 of the file "Decision.java".

Answer (score 8):

You probably didn't enter any command line arguments, so the `args` array is of length 0, hence the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Check the length first, and short-circuit your condition if the length isn't at least 1:

```
if (args.length >= 1 && args[0].equals("xyz"))
```

`args[0]` won't be evaluated, and won't throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, if `args.length >= 1` is `false`, which makes the whole condition `false`.

Comment: I don't mean to sound like a total noob, but I don't really understand what you're saying.

I edited the code but it still doesn't work, instead I get about 10 different messages 

e.g: "at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(NativeMethod)"
followed by 9 other lines or so

Comment: What exception message are you getting?  The line `at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(NativeMethod)` doesn't mean anything by itself.

Comment: "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Decision (wrong name: Decision)

Comment: Did your compilation succeed?  If not, then you must fix your compiler error before you can run it.

Comment: The program is compiled

Comment: I don't understand how you got the program to run (and generate the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and now that you've compiled the source code again, now Java can't find your .class file.  Make sure you're in the same directory as your `Decision.class` file, assuming you're running it with `java Decision` or `java Decision xyz`.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `args` in the `main()` argument, but checked for `argv[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (argv.length > 0 && argv[0].equals("xyz")) {
   …
} else {
   …
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why dont you just add a check to see if your array is empty? Something like:

```
if(argv.length == 0)
{
    argv[0] = "";
}
//everything else...
```

Comment: This one won't work. An array is not resizable, so if the length is 0, than you can never assign something to the first array index (which is `0`).