# JAVA Maze Solver Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, eclipse, indexoutofboundsexception, solver, maze

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Assignment1.main(Assignment1.java:10)
```

That is the Error I'm getting every time I use args[0] in my main method. But when I use null, my maze solver works.

```
public class Assignment1 {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Maze newMaze = new Maze(null);
    System.out.println("Solution Path:");
    newMaze.findPath();
} }
```

and the output is:

```
Solution Path:
C 
I 
S 
1 
1 
A 
B 
0
```

Comment: you mean `Maze newMaze = new Maze(arg[o]);` is throwing exception ?

Comment: Please post the full code.  No one can tell you what is wrong with `Maze` without seeing the code.

Comment: Possible dupicates [Array index out of bounds when getting arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526899/array-index-out-of-bounds-when-getting-arguments)